# How to wait for condition ready, and exclude others

Tags: kubectl

I have an installation where I need some pods to be ready. Therefore I use this

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready --timeout=60s -n some-namespace --all pods
```

Problem is that there are some pods running jobs where there condition status is Completed, and therefore wait hangs as the condition never will be ready.

Is it possible to wait for all but the ones running jobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All jobs are given a label of "job-name" so you can filter based on whether the pod has that label:

```
kubectl wait --selector='!job-name' \
--for=condition=ready --timeout=60s -n some-namespace --all pods
```

If you don't want to skip all jobs, just the ones in Completed, you can filter on "status.phase" instead:

```
kubectl wait --field-selector=status.phase!=Succeeded \
--for=condition=ready --timeout=60s -n some-namespace --all pods
```

Comment: This is the answer I have been looking for. `--field-selector=status.phase!=Succeeded ` is very helpful. Thanks a lot.